# Preventing DoS and flooding attacks on wireless MANET network

Tags: wifi, denial-of-service

How can I prevent DoS/flooding attacks on a wireless [MANET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network#Mobile_ad_hoc_networks_(MANETs)) network?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269278496_An_efficient_scheme_to_prevent_DDoS_flooding_attacks_in_mobile_ad-hoc_network_MANET

Comment: By their very nature, you cannot prevent flooding. To prevent flooding, you need a control layer or a gate.

Comment: @schroeder: You mean, because they are ad-hoc, and there is not a central controlling module for all the network?

Comment: That's correct. And since flooding is a network issue, you need a network control.